# SSRS not displaying data but displays data when query runned in tsql

Tags: sql, t-sql, reporting-services, sql-server-2008-r2, bids

I have a SSRS report that do not display data in preview mode. However, when I run the same query in SQL Server 2008 R2 I can retrieve the results

What could cause this?

I also used Set FMTOnly to off because I use temptables.

Comment: You could have bad cached data - try closing BIDS, delete all the *.rdl.data files in the project folder, then reload the report.

Comment: @IanPreston where can i see the rdl data files? sorry im new to this.

Comment: They will be in the same location as the actual rdl files; it depends on how you set up your project/solution. Just go to the root solution directory and search in that and all child folders.

Comment: @IanPreston still the same results

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you use "SQL Server Business Intelligence Development Studio" not "Report Builder" then on reporting services (where is you table):

1. click View -> Properties Window (or just press F4)
2. select the tablix
3. on properties window find "General" and in the "DataSetName" choose your "Dataset"
4. On tablix fields set values from your "DataSets"

Or just do like here(from 8:50): http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HM_dquiikBA

Answer (score 4):

**The Best solutio**
**Select the entire row and change the font to arial or any other font other than segoe UI**

1. default font
   [default font](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WbRRD.png)
2. no display in preview
   [no display in preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8diWq.png)
3. changed font first row
   [changed font first row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QcN0E.png)
4. first row is displayed in preview
   [first row is displayed in preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O2Qml.png)
5. changed secon row font
   [changed secon row font](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WOSiK.png)
6. data is displayingig
   [data is displayingi](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6KsTI.png)

Answer (score 1):

A workaround should be:

1) Select the parameters and click on View Report (you will not see nothing or some cells will display content and some not)

2) Click on Print Layout (next to the printer)

You will be able to see content. If you have expand/collapse functionality and then you will not be able to interact with the UI.

Answer (score 1):

I faced similar issues. If you remove/delete the parameter, open the dataset definition and refresh the fields, the parameter should be recreated. Then run the report. It worked for me.